# How to upload a non Mura Theme to Mura

Tags: mura

I would like to be able to upload my own theme to Mura. Through my research, I was able to find how to upload Mura theme to Mura but not non-Mura themes. I would like to know the process of uploading my own theme.

Comment: See the Mura documentation on how to create your own "themes" - [Creating Layout Templates](https://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/creating-layout-templates/) Actually, you should probably start at the beginning of the [Theme Developers documentation](https://docs.getmura.com/v7/theme-developers/introduction/)

Comment: @Miguel-F: As far as my understanding, the steps that are for Mura 7 documentation differs in Mura 6. Unless I am understanding the documentation incorrectly

Comment: Yes, they are different. You did not mention which Mura version you are using. For Mura 6 check the [Theme Development Open Forum](https://docs.getmura.com/v6/videos/webinars/theme-development-open-forum/)

Answer (score 0):

@user9808783,

Converting any theme into a "Mura" theme really isn't all that difficult, if you have some basic front-end development experience.

The current version of Mura is 7.1, and everything you need to know about implementing a custom theme into Mura can be found at https://docs.getmura.com/v7-1/theme-developers/introduction/.

If you're running on an older version of Mura (e.g., v6.x), similar information is available at https://docs.getmura.com/v6/front-end/a-typical-workflow/. Some videos are also available at https://docs.getmura.com/v6/videos/integrating-themes-into-mura-cms/.

However, I highly recommend upgrading to the latest version to take advantage of the many enhancements Mura has to offer.

Cheers!

Comment: I have gone through the documentation to upload a non mura theme. I will attempt once more with the information you have providing. Thank You